# Creating this tree structure with LaTeX

Tags: diagrams, tikz-trees

I would like to easily create tree-like structures like

```
D─┬───────────┬───A
  R─┬───A─┬─A R─┐  
    R─┐   R     R  
      R
```

D is the top root node. It starts a horizontal line to the right, which stands for the "same level". This horizontal line can have more letters `A` threaded at any position, which do not have additional semantic meaning. These letters `A` always have a line incoming from the left.

The more interesting feature is that a horizontal line can split downwards to a child (base) node `R` which always have a line incoming from the top. This split can happen at multiple positions on the horizontal baseline. The child nodes recursively start a new virtual block and hence are usually continued by an outgoing horizontal line to the right.- Hence, the `R` next to the `D` effectively starts the whole thing again in its own "bounding box" (here marked with `+`).

```
D─┬───────────────┬───A
  +++++++++++     R─┐
 +R─┬───A─┬─A+      R 
 +  R─┐   R  +     
 +    R      + 
  +++++++++++
```

If for a node there are no more nodes connected to the right, then the horizontal outgoing line is not shown. And of course tree/text overlap needs to be avoided, i.e. some horizontal lines need to stretch far enough before starting a new child node. A type `A` node also should only appear after all previous child blocks have completed to the left of them.

What would be the best way to create such a tree-like drawing in LaTeX?

I've found `\usetikzlibrary{trees}` which goes in this direction, but I'm not sure how to flip the example, how to make multiple letters on a horizontal line, how to control text overlap, etc...

Any good suggestion how to recreate that diagram?

There is a working answer with manually positioning everything, but I hope there is another solution like tikz-tree which can calculate the positioning automatically for me, so that I only specify the child-node relations.

With arbitrary and longer labels:

```
D─┬───────────────────────G─┬─────C
  Cc─┬─────────Aa─┬──Aaaa   Eee─┐  
     Bbb─┐        Dd            A  
         Aaaaa
```

Comment: I am not so adapt at using TikZ that I can provide you with an answer. I took a look at the manual (chapter 21) and at the examples about the options in the tree-library as shown in VisualTikZ. See from page 187 onwards in this link https://mirrors.evoluso.com/CTAN/info/visualtikz/VisualTikZ.pdf. Perhaps those examples provide you ideas how to proceed.

Comment: Could you explain the "tree" structure more? Is D the root with children C, A, A? But what is C on the right? Whose child is E? You could draw this manually with tikz of course, but for automation we need more information.

Comment: It is unclear to me why the C (seemingly a child of D) is to the right of D, but the A (a child of E) would be to the right and below of E. What is the rule for this?

Comment: @dexteritas I've added some explanation and I renamed the nodes to show the 2 types ("D" is just the top "R" node)

Comment: @JasperHabicht See new explanation with node renamed

Comment: This question is not so concise, but the asker was trying hard to describe the situation he faced. I voted to reopen the question.

Comment: Do you actually need the line coming from the top to hit the `A` in `Aaaaa` or is it okay if the line is centered?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I'm not completely decided. For my Ascii art it was easier to make it left. But if you could mention an easy way to switch between both, I'd have a look what's more pleasing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Variant with parameter for label

#### Adaptations

- see original variant below for more description
- `\nodeD`, `\nodeR` and `\nodeA` each have now one parameter to set the text.
- Here I used relative positioning instead of absolute. Therefore, different text lengths are considered.
- I set `base node/.style={draw, dashed}` just for clarification

#### Result

[image]

#### Code

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\def\nodedistance{5mm}
\def\treeY{0}

\newcounter{treeRnode}
\setcounter{treeRnode}{0}
\newcounter{treeAnode}
\setcounter{treeAnode}{0}

\def\lastXnode{}

\newcommand{\nodeD}[1]{%
    \node[D] (D0) at (0,0) {#1};
    \csdef{treeLastY\treeY}{D0}
    \xdef\lastXnode{D0}
}

\newcommand{\nodeR}[1]{%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\lastY{\treeY}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\treeY{\treeY+1}
    \ifcsdef{treeLastY\treeY}{%
        \node[R, anchor=west] (R\arabic{treeRnode}) at ([xshift=\nodedistance] \csuse{treeLastY\treeY}.east-|\lastXnode.east) {#1};
    }{%
        \node[R, below right=of \csuse{treeLastY\lastY}] (R\arabic{treeRnode}) {#1};
    }
    \draw (\csuse{treeLastY\lastY}) -| (R\arabic{treeRnode});
    \csxdef{treeLastY\treeY}{R\arabic{treeRnode}}
    \xdef\lastXnode{R\arabic{treeRnode}}
    \stepcounter{treeRnode}
}

\newcommand{\nodeA}[1]{%
    \node[A, anchor=west] (A) at ([xshift=\nodedistance] \csuse{treeLastY\treeY}.east-|\lastXnode.east) (A\arabic{treeAnode}) {#1};
    \draw (\csuse{treeLastY\treeY}) -- (A\arabic{treeAnode});
    \csxdef{treeLastY\treeY}{A\arabic{treeAnode}}
    \xdef\lastXnode{A\arabic{treeAnode}}
    \stepcounter{treeAnode}
}

\newcommand{\branchend}{%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\treeY{\treeY-1}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance=\nodedistance,
    base node/.style={draw, dashed},
    D/.style={base node},
    R/.style={base node},
    A/.style={base node},
]
    \nodeD{$D_1$ with longer text}
        \nodeR{$R_1$}
            \nodeR{$R_2$ with longer text}
                \nodeR{$R_3$}
                \branchend
            \branchend
        \nodeA{$A_1$}
            \nodeR{$R_4$}
            \branchend
        \nodeA{$A_2$ with longer text}
        \branchend
        %
        \nodeR{$R_5$}
            \nodeR{$R_6$}
            \branchend
        \branchend
    \nodeA{$A_3$}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Variant without parameters (original)

#### Description

I defined some commands that can be used within tikz:

- `\nodeD`, `\nodeR` and `\nodeA` for the different node types
- `\branchend` to stop a branch and go up one level.

I used counters `treeRnode` and `treeAnode` to name the nodes and variables `\treeX` and `\treeY` to save the current position.
Futhermore, `\treeLastY<y>` saves the last node in layer `<y>`.

So the code for the given tree is in my syntax:

```
\nodeD
    \nodeR
        \nodeR
            \nodeR
            \branchend
        \branchend
    \nodeA
        \nodeR
        \branchend
    \nodeA
    \branchend
    %
    \nodeR
        \nodeR
        \branchend
    \branchend
\nodeA
```

The indentation in the source code is just for readability. So, this would be the same:

```
\nodeD\nodeR\nodeR\nodeR\branchend\branchend\nodeA\nodeR\branchend\nodeA\branchend\nodeR\nodeR\branchend\branchend\nodeA
```

#### Result

[image]

#### Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\def\treeX{0}
\def\treeY{0}

\newcounter{treeRnode}
\setcounter{treeRnode}{0}
\newcounter{treeAnode}
\setcounter{treeAnode}{0}

\newcommand{\nodeD}{%
    \node[D] (D0) at (0,0) {D};
    \csdef{treeLastY\treeY}{D0}
}

\newcommand{\nodeR}{%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\treeX{\treeX+1}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\lastY{\treeY}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\treeY{\treeY+1}
    \node[R] (R\arabic{treeRnode}) at (\treeX, -\treeY) {R};
    \draw (\csuse{treeLastY\lastY}) -| (R\arabic{treeRnode});
    \csxdef{treeLastY\treeY}{R\arabic{treeRnode}}
    \stepcounter{treeRnode}
}

\newcommand{\nodeA}{%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\treeX{\treeX+1}
    \node[A] (A) (A\arabic{treeAnode}) at (\treeX, -\treeY) {A};
    \draw (\csuse{treeLastY\treeY}) -- (A\arabic{treeAnode});
    \csxdef{treeLastY\treeY}{A\arabic{treeAnode}}
    \stepcounter{treeAnode}
}

\newcommand{\branchend}{%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\treeY{\treeY-1}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    base node/.style={},
    D/.style={base node},
    R/.style={base node},
    A/.style={base node},
]
    \nodeD
        \nodeR
            \nodeR
                \nodeR
                \branchend
            \branchend
        \nodeA
            \nodeR
            \branchend
        \nodeA
        \branchend
        %
        \nodeR
            \nodeR
            \branchend
        \branchend
    \nodeA
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks good! branchend goes up in the hierarchy? Could you please adapt it so that D/R/A labels are variable (math) expressions (i.e. text)? I still have only those 2 types, but I need to give a different displayed label to each node. I hope it still would work with avoiding overlap. It could be the solution :)

Comment: Yes, `\branchend` goes up in the hierarchy. So you want arbitrary text in the node, instead of just these single letters? I didn't read this in the question. Then the code would have to be adjusted to accommodate differently sized nodes.

Comment: Oh sorry for not being explicit enough. Yes, arbitrary labels. And the overlapping avoiding may become trickier. Is it solvable?

Comment: Also the A-type nodes should not appear before all of the sub-tree is closed to the left of it (in the current version is fine!)

Comment: I added a variant where you can set the label text. But I would have to make some more changes so it works also for longer texts. Maybe you could add an image to your question how it should look like, if there is a longer text (shoud there be a maximum text width and linebreaks?).

Comment: I will use some code to generate the TeX. So it may be complex. I'm thinking if you can use a command like \getWidthOf(repeat text) it would be fine. This would be for extending the horizontal lines. Would that work?

Comment: I've added a long label version to the question

Comment: I made some more adaptations to allow also longer text nodes.

Comment: Brilliant! I think that's it. Thanks a lot :) I'll test it to see if there is no unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 5):

TikZ is a multi-purpose drawing system with `\draw` and `\node` (a `coordinate` is a special `node`). Here is my suggestion. The code is self-explained (a bit care on `+` and `++`).

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path 
(0,0) node[left]  (D) {D}
(5,0) node[right] (A) {A}
(4,0)  coordinate (P1) 
++(0,-.5)    node (P2) {R}
++(.5,-.5)   node (P3) {R}
(.5,0) coordinate (T1)
++(0,-.5)    node (T2) {R}
++(.5,-.5)   node (T3) {R}
++(.5,-.5)   node (T4) {R}
(T2)
+(2.5,0)  node (A2) {A}
+(1.5,0)  node (A1) {A}
+(2,-.5)  node (A3) {R}
;
\draw[thick,magenta] (D)--(A) 
(P1)--(P2)-|(P3)
(T1)--(T2)-|(T3)-|(T4)
(T2)--(A1)--(A2)-|(A3)
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's my approach with `forest`.

Rules:

1. One empty root.
2. The nodes on the same visual level are siblings.
3. Should nodes connect to their previous sibling use `connect left`.

   If you have to customize all edges or want to place nodes along these edges more work might be necessary.
4. *Note:* Some line segments are drawn multiple times when `connect left` connects to a sibling that has children on its own.

   In a proper PDF viewer this shouldn't be noticable, less so on paper. (Don't trust the picture I added to the answer.)

The `gere tree` style install a few things:

1. The parent is a coordinate not a node (not really necessary but why bother).

   The edges to its children are hidden and its children have no `l` meaning there's no vertical space above the first *visual* row.
2. The first children (except the one in the first row) get a previous sibling that gets hidden. This shifts the *first*  child to the right without messing with the *ls* coordinate system.
3. `fit = rectangle` implements your

   > And of course tree/text overlap needs to be avoided, i.e. some horizontal lines need to stretch far enough before starting a new child node. A type `A` node also should only appear after all previous child blocks have completed to the left of them.
4. The `edge path'` in `for tree`

   ```
   edge path'={
     ([xshift={\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}+.4em}].north west) |- (!u)}
   ```

   sets all edges to a `(child) |- (parent)` path (meaning up from the children and then orthogonally to the parent which will always be to the left).

   It is now setup in such a way that it connects the children roughly above the first (capital) letter. For hitting the true horizontal center of the first letter much more work is needed.

   If the line should hit the children  centered across the whole width, simply use

   ```
   edge path' = {() |- (!u)}
   ```

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{
  connect left/.style={% don't connect to parent but to previous sibling
    tikz+={\draw()--(!p);}, no edge},
  gere tree/.style={
    shape=coordinate,               % parent hidden
    for tree={
      calign=first, fit=rectangle,
      edge path'={
        ([xshift={\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}+.4em}].north west)|-(!u)}},
    for children={
      no edge,                      % parent hidden
      before computing xy={l=+0pt}, % parent hidden
      where n children>={0}{prepend={[,phantom]}}{},% invisible sibling at first
    }
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest} gere tree
[
  [D
    [Cc
      [Bbb
        [Aaaaa]]]
    [Aa, connect left
      [Dd]]
    [Aaaa, connect left]
  ]
  [G, connect left
    [Eee
      [A]]
  ]
  [C, connect left]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: This could be a very neat approach! I do need arbitrary labels for the nodes. I tried removing the LaTeX line but got an error. Before removing the line the diagram was actually wrong. What do you mean by providing style A-node?

Comment: Also, that there are 2 lines going off from the D to the right which are off by one pixel. At least when I zoom in in my output. But maybe it's just my rendering.

Comment: (when I tried make the 2nd `A` a longer text, weirdly the diagram turned out wrong)

Comment: @Gere I've updated my answer to allow for arbitrary text. You need to specify `connect left` with the children that connect with their previous siblings and not their parent. The “2 lines” should only be an artefact of bad PDF rendering, if I zoom in [the lines line up perfectly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttOFV.png).

Comment: Yes, it would be nicer if we don't need to overlap lines but it either needs a little bit manual work or someone with a better understanding of `forest`. (I have ideas but I don't know how to implement them.)

Comment: Wow, that's much more concise. I'll see what I use in the long run. Starting a new bracket for same-level A-node is a bit unusually, but I see how to do it. Thanks!